# How to custom response in asp.net web api2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-web-api, linq-to-entities

the problem in this function when add this two lines.

```
UserImage = GetImagePath(db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == p.User_ID).Image),  
InsertDate = p.InsertDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

I need to custom Image Path and custom date format,show this problem.
**LINQ to Entities** does not recognize the method `System.String ToString(System.String)` method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

```
private static string GetImagePath(string ImageName)
{
    return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["websiteurl"].ToString() + "/uploads/" + ImageName;
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("Comments")]
public IHttpActionResult Comments(string Post_ID)
{
    var list = db
        .ShalehComments
        .Where(p => p.Shaleh_ID == Post_ID && p.ParentID == 0)
        .Select(p => new {
            ID = p.ID,
            Comment = p.Comment,
            User = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Id == p.User_ID).FullName,
            UserImage = GetImagePath(db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == p.User_ID).Image),//here problem
            InsertDate = p.InsertDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")//and here
    }).ToList();

    return Ok(
        new
        {
            result = true,
            data = list
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurred because Entity Framework does not know how to execute `.ToString()` or `GetImagePath` method in `sql`. So you should load the data by using `ToList`.So you try something like:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Comments")]
public IHttpActionResult Comments(string Post_ID)
{
    var list = db
        .ShalehComments
        .Where(p => p.Shaleh_ID == Post_ID && p.ParentID == 0)
        .ToList()//add ToList
        .Select(p => new {
            ID = p.ID,
            Comment = p.Comment,
            User = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Id == p.User_ID).FullName,
            UserImage = GetImagePath(db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == p.User_ID).Image),
            InsertDate = p.InsertDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")//and here
    }).ToList();

    return Ok(
        new
        {
            result = true,
            data = list
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: But this method is expensive in performance. Are there other better ways?

Comment: another way you can do all conversion into SQL Query. but in EF when you execute sql query it return `IEnumerable` but it's **expensive** too. so i thing it better.

Comment: @WebDeveloper a stored procedure?

Comment: @PhilCooper If you use EF then same result as Raw Query .you get the result as `IEnumerable`